# not being able to Login in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.3

not being able to login in laravel, on login every time it redirect to login page instead of home page, here is my code

this is my controller code where i hav written d login code

```
public function loginprocess(Request $request){
    $username = $request->get('username');
    $password = $request->get('password');

    $checkuser = Users::selectRaw("Count(*) as Total")->where('email','=',$email)->first();

    if(intval($checkuser->Total) > 0){
        $getpassword = Users::select("password")->where('email','=',$email)->first();
        if(password_verify($password,$getpassword->password)){
        //if($username == $checkuser && $password == $getpassword){
            $request->session()->set('email',$email);
            return redirect('/home');
        }else{
            return redirect('/login');
        }
    }else{
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

Route code where it should go after login

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'checkuser'],function(){
    Route::get('/home','HomeController@index');
});
```

here is my HTML code of form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="loginprocess">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
         <div class="form-group fg-float">
               <div class="fg-line">
                   <label class="fg-label">Email Address</label>
                   <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" class="input-sm form-control fg-input">
               </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group fg-float">
               <div class="fg-line">
                    <label class="fg-label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="input-sm form-control fg-input">
                </div>
           </div>

           <button class="btn palette-Teal bg" name="Login">Sign in</button>

           <div class="m-t-20">
                <a data-bg="blue" class="palette-Teal text d-block m-b-5" href="register">Create an Account</a>
                <a data-bg="purple" class="palette-Teal text" href="forget">Forgot Password?</a>
           </div>
</form>
```

please help

Comment: Just asking...why do you write own login code?
And, can you show code of checkuser middleware.

Comment: @Bostjan <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckUser
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->session()->get('email') === null){
            return redirect('/login');
        }elseif($request->session()->get('email') !== null){
            return redirect('/home');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}

Comment: @Aavin if my answer helped you, please also mark it as the answer. Please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `$email` variable that you call here `$request->session()->set('email',$email);` does not exist anywhere before that line. Add `$email = $request->get('email');` just below the `$password = $request->get('password');`.

Now, some convention. Why is you are `Users` model in Plural?
I gather you want to roll your own login and not use the default login; All good. But please, do some research on that. Laravel provides a great way to do that out of the box too:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    // Authentication passed...
    return redirect()->intended('home');
}
```

Also reading your code. It appears you are saving plain text passwords. Please, do hash user's password as a habit. Laravel does that out of the box with `Hash::make('password');` 
Read more here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3

Comment: still can't login